# stop jQuery DRAGEND link click when dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I was reading many posts carefully and tried out a lot, but couldn't find a solution to my problem. I am using a jQuery dragend source to make a part of the Website draggable to scroll some small images horizontally. On clicking the images a big slideshow-popup opens.

But  whenever I drag an image and drop the mouse within this image, it will call the link to open the popup-gallery. I don't know if I made any mistake by trying out any of the solutions that exist.

HTML:

```
<div id="demo" class="galerie">
    <div class="item">
        <a href="..." class="swipebox">
            <img src="..." border=0 width="100%" alt="image">
        </a>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var BODY = $("body"),
    container = $("#demo"),
    pageElements;
    $(window).on("ready resize", function(event) {

        ...

        container.dragend({
            pageContainer: "#container",
            itemsInPage: itemsInPage,
            pageClass: "item",
            afterInitialize: function() {
                this.container.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        });
    });
});
```

All I need is to stop the link from being active when the gallery is dropped.